# Conditionally rendering field validators

Tags: c#, .net

I have some front-end markup that looks like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirst" />

<% if(DisplayRemainingFields) { %>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecond" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSecond" />
<% } %>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

and in my code-behind I have something like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsValid) {return;}

    //Process fields
}
```

If `DisplayRemainingFields` is false (Preventing `txtSecond` and `RequiredFieldValidator2` from being rendered), `Page.IsValid` will always return false, but if I comment out `RequiredFieldValidator2`, then `Page.IsValid` returns true. Looking at the rendered source code in Chrome, it's clear that the controls aren't added to the page so why would `Page.IsValid` return false under these circumstances, and how can I make this work by using  conditional statements in my front-end markup?

Answer (score 2):

While you are not rendering the controls to the browser, they are still being instantiated by ASP.Net. Since they're contained in Page.Validators collection they will affect the Page lifecycle. Set the Enabled flag on the RequiredFieldValidator to DisplayRemainingFields.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. Also, I'm assuming you meant `DisplayRemainingFields` instead of `!DisplayRemainingFields`

Comment: I did mean DisplayRemainingFields. Good catch, and I'm editing the answer. Could you put a debug point on Page.IsValid in order to interrogate the Page.Validators collection to verify it's the RequiredFieldValidator2 that's causing the issue?